# Remap typescript moment.Moment type(s) to my extended type

Tags: typescript, type-mapping

I'm using the **MomentJS** library but instead of directly using the `Moment` objects I use my own extension with some extras on top of the `Moment` instances:

```
function myMoment(...args: any[]) : MyMoment {
    let instance = <MyMoment>moment.apply(this, args);

    instance.toString = () => {
        return 'Think for a Moment';
    }

    instance.isMyMoment = true;

    return instance;
}
```

I've also written a definition file **MyMoment.d.ts** that remaps existing `moment.Moment` so that all functions `(...) => Moment` become `(...) => MyMoment`.

```
declare const myMoment = moment;

declare type MyMoment = {
    [K in keyof moment.Moment]: ReturnType<moment.Moment[K]> extends moment.Moment
        ? moment.Moment[K] extends (...a: infer A) => moment.Moment
            ? (...a: A) => MyMoment // remap the return type of functions that return Moment instance
            : never                 // this will never map
        : moment.Moment[K];         // other return types should be preserved
} & {
    isMyMoment: true;               // distinguish my moments
};
```

Problem is that some functions take parameters of type 'Moment' i.e. `diff()`. If I have two instances of `MyMoment` and call `diff()` I get a type incompatibility error:

> ***TS2345**: Argument of type 'MyMoment' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MomentInput'.
>
> Type 'MyMoment' is not assignable to type 'Moment'.*

My type mapper above should also remap all function parameters' types from `Moment` to `MyMoment`. Unfortunately some of those parameter types (i.e. `MomentInput`) are even union types of which one of the types is type `Moment`.

**I don't have a slightest clue (yet) how to rewrite my mapper to also remap those?**

### Or use an approach to fool the compiler

I could convince the compiler that `MyMoment` is actually just a `Moment` from the type perspective which *almost* is except for the extra boolean prop so in reality `MyMoment extends Moment`, but execution wise it's not important and it wouldn't flip the compiler. I tried to rewrite the definitions file.

```
declare const myMoment = moment;

declare namespace moment {
    interface Moment extends Object {
        isMyMoment?: true;
    }
}

declare type MyMoment = moment.Moment;
```

The interesting thing is that I don't see any errors in VSCode and even intellisense works, but my compiler complains:

> ***TS2339**: Property 'diff' does not exist on type 'Moment'.*

So still doesn't work as it should.

I may be close with this solution, but I would need your extra pair of eyes on the code above **or**...

**Maybe there's some third way that I'm not even thinking about?**

Answer (score 0):

I think your "fool the compiler" approach using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) should work. If it's not working I expect the problem to be with your compiler setup and not with declaration merging itself.

---

My actual recommended approach here is probably to make a copy of [the type declaration file for moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/b7ec8e2ec068e03de4f832f28362675bb9e02261/moment.d.ts), modify the definition of `Moment` to include your extra properties, possibly do a find-and-replace of the word `Moment` with `MyMoment`, and save it as your own declaration file.  This is a manual process which could obviously diverge from the definitions in moment.js, but it is *straightforward*, which is nice.

---

I'm intrigued by your "type mapping" approach, where you essentially simulate declaration merging.  Let's say `DeclMerge<T, U>` takes a type `T` and merges `U` into it recursively, so that all references to `T` inside the definition of `T` also have `U` merged into them.  Moreover, let's say `DeclMerge<T, U, S>` takes a type `T` and merge `U` into all references to `S` inside of it, where `S` defaults to `T`.  That way we can describe the recursive nature of `DeclMerge` by keeping `U` and `S` fixed while changing `T`.

I think such a thing is **fraught with peril**.  Mapped types and other type juggling don't do very well in the face of generics, or overloads, or `private` and `protected` properties and methods... so I'd expect some edge cases where things fail spectacularly.   That being said, the idea is so interesting that I will attempt it, even though I wouldn't recommend using it in actual production code without a lot of testing.  I can't resist; here is my attempt at an implementation of `DeclMerge`:

```
type DeclMerge<T, U, S = T> =
   T extends any ? ((T extends S ? U : unknown) & (
      T extends readonly any[] ? { [K in keyof T]: DeclMerge<T[K], U, S> } :
      T extends object ? (
         { [K in keyof T]: DeclMerge<T[K], U, S> } &
         (T extends {
            (...args: infer P): infer R
         } ? {
            (...args: DeclMerge<P, U, S>): DeclMerge<R, U, S>
         } : unknown) &
         (T extends {
            new(...args: infer P): infer R
         } ? {
            new(...args: DeclMerge<P, U, S>): DeclMerge<R, U, S>
         } : unknown)) :
      T)) : never;
```

Blah, that's long and complicated, and really screams "there will be terrible edge cases".  Anyway the approach here is:

- Make sure that we [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the replacement across any unions in `T`.  So if `Foo` becomes `Bar`, we want `Foo | string` to become `Bar | string`... we do this by wrapping the whole thing in the distributive conditional type `T extends any ? ... : never`.
- If `T` is assignable to `S`, let's intersect the output type with `U`.  Otherwise, don't.
- If `T` is an arraylike thing, use a [mapped type on arrays/tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to transform each of the elements of `T` separately.
- If `T` is an object type, then map each of its properties, as well as the parameters and return types of its call or construct signature if it has one.
- If `T` is a primitive type, leave it alone.

---

Let me make my own class and see how the compiler maps it:

```
declare class Foo {
   static instance: Foo;
   constructor(x: string, otherFoo?: Foo);
   x: string;
   y: number;
   z: Foo | null;
   acceptFoo(x: Foo): number;
   produceFoo(): Foo;
   arr: Foo[];
}

type MyFooCtor = DeclMerge<typeof Foo, { extraProp: number }, Foo>;
```

You can see that the `Foo` class has a lot of self-references in it.  The `MyFooCtor` type is what you get if you take the type of the `Foo` constructor and merge `{extraProp: number}` into all occurrences of `Foo`.  Here's the test:

```
declare const MyFoo: MyFooCtor;
const m = new MyFoo("hello");
m.extraProp.toFixed();
m.x.toUpperCase();
m.y.toFixed();
m.produceFoo().extraProp
m.arr[0].arr[0].extraProp
m.acceptFoo(m)
m.z!.extraProp;
new MyFoo("", m)
m.acceptFoo(new Foo("")); // error! expecting MyFoo, not Foo
MyFoo.instance.extraProp
```

That all looks good to me.  The compiler is dutifully adding `extraProp` where I expect it to, and specifically the transformed `acceptFoo()` wants its argument to be an instance of `MyFoo` and not `Foo`.

---

For `Moment`, then, you might want to write this:

```
type MyMoment = DeclMerge<moment.Moment, { isMyMoment: true }>;

declare const myMoment1: MyMoment;
declare const myMoment2: MyMoment;
myMoment1.diff(myMoment2);

declare const moment: moment.Moment;
myMoment1.diff(moment); // error!
// Property 'isMyMoment' is missing in type 'Moment'
```

That looks like what you wanted, right?  Maybe... but I wouldn't trust it.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5xBEBTAdvAMyizgHJMd9SAoWmATzGzgBFsBjAGwFlsoBzbAB4AKgBo4AVQkBlOAF44IgHwLqcDSLjYAHjDwATdMlz04AfjgAKK1t37cRuHMuS4ALjgBXXAGtcEADuuACUcABk1uoaMXZ6huhQ2MgGELicZib0ANoAuhZwAN5w2QDScMC4cL7Y9BAESrmebFy8AsIiZbkS0s6qAL4e0TFK2vGO6BAARgBWHPCWVsMjGsVlFVU1dQ0iTawcPHyCol09sgMRyyu2Yw5OhVcrGlYAdG-IAqielQR8cAAKIW+uF+UDgACVHjFBpYHk8nq93p9mgc2sd-mc+kD9q0jsJwZiZMooRpBp4fP4gqFLvDnnE7ug4bSYrhsIFES8PvwvhtQQDsT8-pDmTCiiSRqz2W9OcicYd2kIMVJztiWvLjgTlX1xWTvH4AsEQmF3I8REaPHBWQA3PgAbloBgOH2YXDQ6AAYhAIGKYqgYMgYMB2Bs-SZ2NhPJ6IPaYuw0n6oF52DBoFYdJ4E5V+BIIDAABZ8KPmSNekIxjTpuCZ3D8W1wYb0Ty4LwgKZ24YALxL3oAPpavJxOOWUOxw2AYFG093sc3W+2YmBiAYk9hJ9io8OPlBu3l7f06IxmNx6FGAMIpsGKNVo4QMJj1OBRiTFexQZD-YhgJstttg-oSKNlHtR1XSSOA41wP04GPKNPBgr1z2ge0IKgkAFEtNloJPL0rAAIgLQcIFwstqBAF5X3fT8XhTd1gB0bADCsEiyJ0aiIEkMAmCgU80GwJj7TI+g2No+jGOYl5FwgZdwzXci9DfD8IDAUiZSgbIAAZclUjStIoxTlLI5BR2wcdJxAEIVI7ABCOSYAUz97UlLDJ1w3CJHMlSjLHCccKclziLLOAAHogu0KBiCgKyxiYZMs2cr0JACeAo2oeCIBeSpQ1wcNbPspTaGoO8j3obgsDweAr1RPEhAocqXlKygYGfCpUGPBrys8OyvGYfogIdJ0wJQ+AQBKsr8AARjg0bGuAgaXXjYbpvKgAmKb2vwASloml4DGAAgCCsEb1pgZaSOoEDOGdcCFowMaYE8Wr8Hqu7NuO8adr2g7HpgQKQrCiKrOoP79L4BgyGAVqtpgUgWowCHUDiyo4CKshjph6ggA)

Comment: The rewriting of lib privided `moment.d.ts` doesn't seem like a viable idea, because I would need to do this every time I'd upgrade the lib. which isn't very clean thing to do. And you're right about the **declaration merging**. The problem was in configuration of my compiler and I've made it work. I've merged my custom property into existing interface and everything seems to compile as it should.